# PushSharp : The maximum number of Send attempts to send the notification was reached! on client server

Tags: ios, push-notification, pushsharp

I am using PushSharp to send push notifications and getting the error 'The maximum number of Send attempts to send the notification was reached!'.

The interesting thing is that from my local server notifications are sent successfully, but when I run on Client Server I am getting above error.

At the this link https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/462, I see you resolved this issue. with the following tricks.
Exported Apple Developer & Distribution Certificates as *.p12 from Keychain of Mac (No Private Keys)
 Added the certificates to the windows keychain of server under personal & trusted roots to match the certs being loaded for the push channel settings
Extended the max re queue property value of service settings to 25, the default is 5

I follow the above, but still issue persists. Any Idea or another way to resolve it ?